# Does pattern matching require having the data on one machine?

Tags: distributed-systems, pattern-recognition

Is it possible to use pattern matching algorithms such as FP-Trees and others on data that resides in multiple machines?

Basically when doing pattern matching do you have to have all your data on the same disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the algorithm.  Most algorithms are designed under the assumption that all the data resides on one machine, but if the data lives on multiple machines, you could of course adapt the algorithm to that situation (potentially with a significant loss of performance).